# Git Submodule vs ignore files

Tags: git

Our project involves many components, for example, login related code is in service folder, ui related code is in UI folder. I want to easy to update the folders and use in another projects.

One solution is to use submodules. But sometimes it is too complicated and easy to be problematic.

I wonder if we can put the component folder in ignore file, and then just put that folder in a separate repo, so that we can just pull and push?

Comment: Why do you think that you even need separate repos/submodules here?

Comment: for example, the ui folder will be used in multiple projects, every time we update the ui, we have to copy and paste to another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are thinking about having separate git projects for each of your components. A project with a demand for any of these components shall then check out in a subfolder of its source tree (or symbolically link to something external). The .gitignore entry will help to prevent an accidential addition to the embracing project.

This will work nicely. I mentioned the symbolic links. If you do not have them, then you effectively create a new branch of your component with every copy and decide what feed back to the remote master. You are likely to create a new branch for local changes that are not relevant for other uses. With symbolic links every change has an immediate effect to every other source tree also linking to it. But you cannot have a branch for single embracing projects since changing the branch will also change all other uses of that symbolically linked folder.

If this is good or bad in my mind depends on the proficiency of your coworkers with git and on the structure (code, updates/releases, distribution, ...) of your project and on how you centrally organise the source code management of your subprojects. I could well imagine that for allowing more external code on remotely accessible repositories, at some point you may appreciate the more formal approach to git sub-projects.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to easy to update the folders and use in another projects.

Have you ever tried composer with private repositories? You can share code between projects easily.